# Vim replace with '/' and numbers

Tags: vim

Vim replace is very hardy to use when I haven't came across problems like this:

1) replace numbers with other text

2) replace text like `/static/` to `www.website.com/`

I assume I need to use some regex to tackle the first problem and some way to get around the `/` mark for the second.

Any quick solutions ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `:%s/\d\+/sometext/g`
2. `:%s/\/static\//www.website.com\//g`

Comment: Easier: to avoid dealing with escapes for the slash, use another separator. `:%s#/static/#www.website.com/#g`